# Return the data from the previous record to the current record

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
 account    contract    price   order
0   B   1222    1000    Original
1   B   1225    2000    1st
2   C   1323    500 2nd
3   D   1449    200 Original
4   D   1223    300 1st
5   D   1224    100 2nd
```

I want the following output:

```
 account    contract    price   order   prev_contract   prev_price
0   B   1222    1000    Original    NaN NaN
1   B   1225    2000    1st 1222.0  1000.0
2   C   1323    500 2nd 1225.0  2000.0
3   D   1449    200 Original    NaN NaN
4   D   1223    300 1st 1449.0  200.0
5   D   1224    100 2nd 1223.0  300.0
```

Each account can have one or more contracts. Contracts for each account are ordered from "Original", "1st", "2nd", and so on (some can get up to 130th). I want to create columns beside the existing dataframe to put the data/record from the previous contract based on the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `shift`

```
out = df.join(df.groupby(['account'])['price','order'].shift(),rsuffix = '_prev')
  account  contract  price     order  price_prev order_prev
0       B      1222   1000  Original         NaN        NaN
1       B      1225   2000       1st      1000.0   Original
2       C      1323    500       2nd         NaN        NaN
3       D      1449    200  Original         NaN        NaN
4       D      1223    300       1st       200.0   Original
5       D      1224    100       2nd       300.0        1st
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try via `groupby()`,`where()`, `shift()` and `join()` method:

```
grouped=df.groupby('account')

df=df.join(grouped[['contract','price']]
           .transform(lambda x:x.where(grouped['account'].transform('count').gt(1))).shift(1)
           .add_prefix('prev_'))
```

Output of `df`:

```
    account     contract    price   order       prev_contract   prev_price
0   B           1222        1000    Original    NaN             NaN
1   B           1225        2000    1st         1222.0          1000.0
2   C           1323        500     2nd         1225.0          2000.0 
3   D           1449        200     Original    NaN             NaN
4   D           1223        300     1st         1449.0          200.0
5   D           1224        100     2nd         1223.0          300.0
```